# checkbox "selecionar todos" jquery e CakePHP

Tags: jquery, checkbox, cakephp-3

Oi, eu tenho um `foreach` num table que lista vários `checkboxes`. Preciso fazer uma função `jquery` que ao clicar no checkbox do `<th>` `selecione todos` os checkboxes do próximo `<td>`.
Olhe meu código:

```
foreach ($controllersActions as $acaoControlador) {
   if ($controlador != $controladorAtual) {
                            $controlador = $controladorAtual;
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                <?php 
                                echo $this->Form->checkbox('all', [
                                    'hiddenField' => false,
                                    'class' => 'all',

                                ]);
                                ?>
                                <?= Inflector::humanize($controladorAtual) ?>
                            </th>   
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left: 20px; width: 10px;">
                                <?=
                                $this->Form->checkbox('permissoes[]', [
                                    'hiddenField' => false,
                                    'value' => $acaoControlador,
                                    marcado($entidade, $acaoControlador)
                                ]);
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?= Inflector::humanize($acaoAtual); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }; ?>
```

ai em cima esta a listagem dos meus checkboxes

em baixo está a minha função jquery:

```
 $('.all').on('click', function(e){
            $this = this;

            $.each($(this).children('tr td').find('checkbox'), function(i, item){
                alert('oi');
              $(item).prop('checked', $this.checked);
            });

          });
      <?= Inflector::humanize($controladorAtual) ?>
         </th>  
  </tr>
```

Uma imagem dos checks na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui o html renderizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém ao clicar no checkbox que dispara essa função, nada acontece.
retirei o código jquery desse exemplo: 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/WPvrj

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Só uma pergunta, a localidade desse código ta solto dentro do html? para que o Jquery funcione, ele deve estar contido dentro da tag <script></script>

Comment: sim sim, está. Só não coloquei no código aqui pra não ficar muita coisa, saca?

Comment: Qual é a estrutura dessa `<table>`? Não percebo o que queres dizer com "ao clicar no checkbox do <th> selecione todos os checkboxes do próximo <td>". Qual é o proximo `td` na tua estrutura?

Comment: Opa, ajustei o código. Quis suprimir, mas acabei esquecendo o fechamento de umas tags.

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio seria interessante colocares o HTML renderizado e especificar quais os `<td>` que devem ser marcados quando esse `.all` estiver também marcado.

Comment: Cara olha só. Há um if que eu monto o th que gera o input[class='all'] que é um checbox. Ao clicar nesse check do if, quero selecionar todos os td que estão fora o if, que é uma listagem então de todas as opções.

Comment: Isso é bem simples de se fazer, mas fica mais fácil dar um exemplo para seu caso se postar o html renderizado, como sugerido pelo @Sergio

Comment: beleza, coloquei um print do html e da tela.

Comment: Assim ficou mais claro! É isto que procuras? -> https://jsfiddle.net/azue5509/

Comment: é quase isso, só que seu código ele seleciona todos os da tela. Tem como limitar pra ele selecionar só até o proximo th ? 
Atualizei as imagens para ficar mais claro

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio ter várias `tr`com `th` na mesma tabela é HTML inválido. Podes dar classes diferentes a esses elementos?

Comment: Sim eu acabei de fazer isso para testar, coloquei a classe 'all' para os checks do header e a classe 'cada' para cada check do 'td'. Mas não consegui rodar.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você deve ter algo para identificar os `checkbox` que serão selecionados, pode ser uma classe em comum, podem estar dentro de uma `div` ou outro bloco qualquer.
Atribua o evento `change` ao `checkbox` que será responsável por selecionar todos e altere o comportamento do `change` para marcar/desmarcar.

O item principal é ter alguma maneira de identificar esse grupo de checkbox, veja o exemplo com os checkbox dentro de uma div.

```js
$('body').on('change', '.all', function() {
  $(this).next('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked); //jQuery <= 1.6 usar attr
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="all" />
<div id="minhaDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="all" />
<div id="minhaOutraDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: eu tentei adaptar isso para a minha estrutura mas não rolou:
$('body').on('change', '.all', function() {
     $(this).next('tr').find( 'input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked); //jQuery <= 1.6 usar attr
   });